# Esri parser conflict with Print Function

Tags: javascript, parsing, esri, arcgis-js-api

So I tried to add Print function on my arcgis map. It's doesn't work at all. So I tried to start new project and figure it out. It worked fine.

Back to my main project, I realized the errors is came from parser itself. When I comment the `parser.parse();` the print function is work but a part of my function didn't work out.

I've tried to add this:

```
<script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            parseOnLoad: false,
            async: true,
            tlmSiblingOfDojo: false           
        }; </script>
```

It doesn't work out.

Here is the print function:

```
    parser.parse();
 esriConfig.defaults.io.corsEnabledServers.push("1xx.1xx.xx.xx2:6443");

        map = new Map("mapDiv", {
          // basemap: "satellite",
          basemap: "topo",
          center: [118,-1],
          zoom: 5,
          sliderStyle: "small"
        });

        printUrl = "https://1xx.1xx.7x.2xx:6443/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task";

        var printInfo = esriRequest({
          "url": printUrl,
          "content": { "f": "json" }
        });
        printInfo.then(dojo.hitch(printUrl,dojo.hitch(map,handlePrintInfo)), handleError);

        function handlePrintInfo(resp) {


          var layoutTemplate, templateNames, mapOnlyIndex, templates;

          layoutTemplate = arrayUtils.filter(resp.parameters, function(param, idx) {
            return param.name === "Layout_Template";
          });

          if ( layoutTemplate.length === 0 ) {
            console.log("print service parameters name for templates must be \"Layout_Template\"");
            return;
          }
          templateNames = layoutTemplate[0].choiceList;

          // remove the MAP_ONLY template then add it to the end of the list of templates 
          mapOnlyIndex = arrayUtils.indexOf(templateNames, "MAP_ONLY");
          if ( mapOnlyIndex > -1 ) {
            var mapOnly = templateNames.splice(mapOnlyIndex, mapOnlyIndex + 1)[0];
            templateNames.push(mapOnly);
          }

          // create a print template for each choice
          templates = arrayUtils.map(templateNames, function(ch) {
            var plate = new PrintTemplate();
            plate.layout = plate.label = ch;
            plate.format = "PDF";
            plate.layoutOptions = { 
              "authorText": "Author.",
              "copyrightText": "<copyright info here>",
              "legendLayers": [], 
              "titleText": "A title", 
              "scalebarUnit": "Kilometers" 
            };
            return plate;
          });

          // create the print dijit
          var printer = new Print({
            "map": map,
            "templates": templates,
            "url": printUrl
          }, dojo.byId("print_map"));
          printer.startup();
        }

        function handleError(err) {
          console.log("Something broke: ", err);
        }
```

How can I make the print function work out without removing `parser.parse();`?

Comment: There is no parser.parse in your code. Where from did you remove it?

Comment: My code is the way too big, I include ` parser.parse();
` above that.

Comment: I edited the code.